# Webbrowser set cookies error

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control

I use Webbrowser control to navigate but encountered "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on the following. Had been googling but no avail. Pls help.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    WebBrowser1.Document.Cookie = "test=1234"        'Error line
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.yahoo.com")
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want to set a cookie, the right way to do so is to use the InternetSetCookie API.

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto , SetLastError=true)] 
private static extern bool InternetSetCookie (string url, string name, string data);

public static bool SetWinINETCookieString(string sURL, string sName, string sData) 
{
    return InternetSetCookie(sURL, sName, sData);
}
```

That will actually set the cookie rather than simply corrupting your HTTP headers.

Comment: I am not sure about "right" so much as "only [known to me] working hack"... the entire WebBrowser situation is sadly cumbersome and limited. The issue with `InternetSetCookie` is that it is not local for the WebBrowser, but has now polluted (possible overwriting a previous cookie) the cookies stored in IE. I am not aware of a way to get "InPrivate" browsing in a WebBrowser control either.

Comment: No, there is no way to run a WebBrowser control in "Isolated" mode. Using InternetSetCookie without an expiration date will create a per-session cookie which isn't used outside your process.

Answer (score 0):

Your WebBrowser.Document is probably a null reference (Nothing) before navigating !

EDIT:
You can request a url using [this Navigate variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161355.aspx) which accepts request headers.
so just use

```
 WebBrowser1.Navigate(url, Nothing, Nothing, "Cookie: test=1234")
```

Comment: So how do i get the webbrowser running?

Comment: WebBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank") solved the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", but the cookies still cannot be set. Can someone shed a light? i had been trying for week.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried that too, when i fiddle the cookie is not there.

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank")
    WebBrowser1.Document.Cookie = "test=1234"
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.yahoo.com")

End Sub
```

End Class